# How to enable/setup log4j for oozi java workflows?

Tags: java, log4j, hdfs, oozie

I'm running an Oozie Java workflow (the jar file is in HDFS), and I'd like to add logging functionality to my application. Does anybody know how to do it? Where should I put my "log4j.properties" file? How can I make log4j to output the log to a location in HDFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in [this documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/AG_OozieLogging.html), you can try adding `oozie-log4j.properties` in your oozie directory (where `workflow.xml` is).

Here are the default settings:

```
log4j.appender.oozie=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy=org.apache.oozie.util.OozieRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.oozie.File=${oozie.log.dir}/oozie.log
log4j.appender.oozie.Append=true
log4j.appender.oozie.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.oozie.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${log4j.appender.oozie.File}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}
log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.MaxHistory=720
```

It also outlines the following restrictions:

> In order for Oozie logging to work 100% correctly, the following restrictions must be observed (described below and in the oozie-log4j.properties file):

- The appender that Oozie uses must be named "oozie" (i.e. log4j.appender.oozie )
- `log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern` must end with `"-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.gz"` or `"-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}"`. If it ends with `".gz"` the old logs will be compressed when rolled
- `log4j.appender.oozie.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern` must start with the value of `log4j.appender.oozie.File`

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting an old thing, but this approach doesn't seem to be working for me. I am on Oozie 4.1.0 (via Cloudera CDH 5.4.4), and the [4.1.0 doc page on logging](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/AG_OozieLogging.html) doesn't say anything about placing this file in the workflow directory.